# SSL certificate installation failure

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I installed official SSL certificate on APIM. Now the carbon Web-app fails to load. Could it be a problem with catalina-server.xml ? All xml are well configured with new keystore and password.

The only ERROR in wso2carbon.log on start-up :

```
TID: [-1] [] [2016-05-10 08:52:45,170] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.CarbonTomcatServiceComponent} -  Error while adding the carbon web-app {org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.CarbonTomcatServiceComponent}
    org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.CarbonTomcatException: Webapp failed to deploy
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:302)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:185)
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.ext.internal.CarbonTomcatServiceComponent.activate(CarbonTomcatServiceComponent.java:59)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
            at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
            at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:260)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.performWork(SCRManager.java:816)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager$QueuedJob.dispatch(SCRManager.java:783)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.WorkThread.run(WorkThread.java:89)
            at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.util.impl.tpt.threadpool.Executor.run(Executor.java:70)
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at org.wso2.carbon.tomcat.internal.CarbonTomcat.addWebApp(CarbonTomcat.java:233)
            ... 17 more
```

Java Version     : 1.8.0_71
Operating System : Linux 2.6.32-573.18.1.el6.x86_64, amd64
User             : xxxx, US-US, Europe/Paris

Thank you

Comment: Which version of API Manager you are using?

Comment: I am using the last version 1.10.0

Comment: have you pointed catalineserver.xml to the new keystore?

Answer (score 0):

if anyone come here.
I just spent two days making this work with a public let's encrypt certificate.

This procedure was done with the wso2am-2.2.0.zip version, it may not work on other versions
I installed it in /opt/wso2

Here is what i did :

These are my variables, the existing jks path, and it's key

```
jks_location="/opt/tomcat/conf/tomcat.jks" jks_password="changeit" key_password="changeit" jks_alias=tomcat server_name="your public server name"
```

I search every file with the wso2carbon.jks keyword
And i replace some certificate values, but not the one concerning the client trust store

```
grep -R wso2carbon.jks  /opt/wso2/ | cut -d ':' -f1 | grep "\.xml$" | grep -v -e ".b$" -e logs -e migration -e "\.db" | sort -u | while read file ; do awk '{if(/<\/[Kk]eyStore/ && q==0 && p==1){print "<KeyAlias>'$jks_alias'</KeyAlias>"}
      if(/<\/[Kk]eyStore>/ || /<\/dataBridgeConfiguration>/ ){p=0;q=0}if($1~/<[Kk]eyStore/ || /<\/dataBridgeConfiguration>/ ){p=1}
      if(/<KeyAlias/ && p==1){q=1}
      if(p==1 && /<Password>/){
        print "                     <Password>'$jks_password'</Password>"
      } else if (p==1 && /<password/){
        print "                     <password>'$jks_password'</password>"
      } else if (p==1 && /<keyStorePassword/){
        print "                     <keyStorePassword>'$jks_password'</keyStorePassword>"
      } else if (p==1 && /<KeyPassword/){
        print "                     <KeyPassword>'$key_password'</KeyPassword>"
      } else if (p==1 && /<KeyAlias/){
        print "                     <KeyAlias>'$jks_alias'</KeyAlias>"
      } else if (p==1 && /<Location/){
        print "                     <Location>'$jks_location'</Location>"
      } else if (p==1 && /<location/){
        print "                     <location>'$jks_location'</location>"
      } else if (p==1 && /<keyStoreLocation/){
        print "                     <keyStoreLocation>'$jks_location'</keyStoreLocation>"
      } else if (/keystoreFile=.*wso2carbon.jks/){
        print "                   keystoreFile=\"'$jks_location'\""
      } else if (/keystorePass="wso2carbon"/){
        print "                   keystorePass=\"'$jks_password'\""
      } else if (/<parameter name="wss.ssl.key.store.file">/){
        print "       <parameter name=\"wss.ssl.key.store.file\">'$jks_location'</parameter>"
      } else if (/<parameter name="wss.ssl.key.store.pass"/){
        print "       <parameter name=\"wss.ssl.key.store.pass\">'$jks_password'</parameter>"
      }
        else  {print}
      }'  $file > "$file".t ; echo "$file" ; cp -a "$file".t "$file" ; done
```

I change the carbon.local.ip in the xml files

```
grep -R 'carbon.local.ip' /opt/wso2/ | cut -d ':' -f1 | grep "\.xml$"  | sort -u | while read file ; do sed -i -e 's/\${carbon.local.ip}/'$server_name'/g' $file ; done
```

I add a server name so you don't get redirect to the IP address on the first page

```
sed -i '/<ServerURL>local/a<!-- Manual add-->\n    <HostName>'$server_name'<\/HostName>\n    <MgtHostName>'$server_name'<\/MgtHostName>' /opt/wso2/repository/conf/carbon.xml
```

I import the root certificate of my existing certificate (i use a public from let's encrypt, but i need to add it anyway, maybe you won't have to)

```
keytool -import -alias lets_encrypt_root -file your-root-file.pem -keystore /opt/wso2/repository/resources/security/client-truststore.jks -storePass wso2carbon
```

If your certificate does not contain "localhost" as an alias
you need to change the https backend call from localhost to your real hostname

```
grep -i -R "https://localhost:" /opt/wso2/ | grep -v '\.log' | cut -d ':' -f1 | sort -u | grep -v '\.t$' | xargs -I file sed -i -e 's|https://localhost:|https://'$server_name:'|g' file
```

If the awk seems complicated, it's because i'm not an expert, some tag can be different when you look at the case (don't know if it's important to leave it that way)
And for example the password tag must only be change when inside the keystore tag.

Hope it helps